# C# Microsoft Graph Api Request_BadRequest

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Every time I try to add a license to a user using the Microsoft Graph Api in C#, I get this error:

Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: License assignment cannot be done for user with invalid usage location.

My code is here

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantid";
var clientId = "clientid";
var clientSecret = "clientsecret";

var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var user = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "test",
    MailNickname = "test",
    UserPrincipalName = "test@example.com",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = "random.1234"
    }
};

var addLicenses = new List<AssignedLicense>()
{
    new AssignedLicense
    {
        SkuId = Guid.Parse("314c4481-f395-4525-be8b-2ec4bb1e9d91")
    }
};
var removeLicenses = Array.Empty<Guid>();

await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(user);
Console.WriteLine("Kullanıcı Açıldı");

await graphClient.Users["test@example.com"]
    .AssignLicense(addLicenses, removeLicenses)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Lisans Eklendi");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new user you need to set `UsageLocation`.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) says that `usageLocation` is required for users that will be assigned licenses due to legal requirement to check for availability of services in countries.

```
var user = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "test",
    MailNickname = "test",
    UserPrincipalName = "test@example.com",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = "random.1234"
    },
    UsageLocation = "TR" // for Turkey
};

// rest of the code without changes
var addLicenses = new List<AssignedLicense>()
{
    new AssignedLicense
    {
        SkuId = Guid.Parse("314c4481-f395-4525-be8b-2ec4bb1e9d91")
    }
};
var removeLicenses = Array.Empty<Guid>();

await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(user);
Console.WriteLine("Kullanıcı Açıldı");

await graphClient.Users["test@example.com"]
    .AssignLicense(addLicenses, removeLicenses)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Lisans Eklendi");
```